# How can I get text from ComboBox?

Tags: java, combobox

I want to get the items of a combobox, and store it in an ArrayList object.

Comment: How exactly did you fail? Please show some code. Tell what happens. Tell what happens not.

Comment: @Johanna - this is not the way to learn.  If / when you get a job they will expect you to be able to figure these things out for yourself.

Comment: Isn't that related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796990/why-this-code-about-combobox-doesnt-work  ?

Comment: @Carlos- it definitely looks like it and she used my exact answer approach.. ;)

Comment: Yes, the other one is the follow on question (and it won't be the last)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [getItemCount](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getItemCount())  to find out how many items are in the `combobox` then make a `for loop` using JComboBox's  [getItemAt](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getItemAt(int)) to store the items in your created `Arraylist`  using the Arraylist `add()`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the selected items (most typical usecase), then just do

```
Object[] allSelectedAsArray = combobox.getSelectedObjects();
List<Object> allSelectedAsList = Arrays.asList(allSelectedAsArray);
```

Otherwise (maybe someone added a value to the combobox on the UI)

```
List<Object> allItemsAsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int index = 0; index < combobox.getItemCount(); index++) {
  Object item = combobox.getItemAt(index);
  allItemsAsList.add(item);
}
```

Comment: I believe OP was referring to all the items in the combobox?

Comment: true, thats why I put a '?' at the end of my comment