# why this code about combobox doesn't work?

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a combobox which stores "Computer ,Code:21","History ,Code:31" and also the number of items can be changed.but when I write this code for getting its items:

```
List<String> bIHELessons = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0;i<jComboBox1.getItemCount();i++) {
   String lessons = (String) jComboBox1.getItemAt(i);
   if (lessons != null&& lessons.trim().length()!=0) {
      bIHELessons.add(lessons);
      System.out.println(bIHELessons.toString());
   }
}
```

it will show these sentences in the console:

[Computer,Code=21]

[Computer,Code=21, History,Code:31]

Comment: What is your question exactly? And what does your program do??
 
I don't program JAVA, but I find it strange that you instantiate an arraylist and assign it to a list of strings.

Your biHELessons.toString() will dump the contents of the items you have added in the loop, so I don't think your result is strange.

Comment: What do you expect the program to do? @Michel `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface.

Comment: Please edit your post and say what you expect to get. Right now it looks ok...

Comment: @Michel: the Arraylist instantiation and assignment to List is a standard Java way of doing things. `ArrayList` is the implementation of the `List` interface, and so it's common to provide consumers of the `Arraylist` just the interface, so that you may change the underlying implementation if you wish (for example to a `LinkedList`) without the calling code having to be changed.

Comment: @Johanna: It's working perfectly, just the output should be `[Computer,Code:21]` with ':' and not '='... Do the `System.out.println` outside the loop (after all) if you want to see only the *final* result

Answer (score 3):

Because you are appending to the list with `bIHELessons.add(..)`. Each subsequent call adds on to the already printed string.

If you want to still add to the ArrayList and print the current item that is in the ArrayList, then use `System.out.println(bIHELessons.get(i));` rather than using what you are now. I also don't think you need to use `toString()` because your objects are already in the type `string`.

Change `System.out.println(bIHELessons.toString());` to `System.out.println(lessons);` if you only want to print the string you are currently iterating on.

Comment: Like he said, you're println statement is printing the entire contents of the List.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see your code is doing what it should be doing.  Are you wanting to know why you are seeing all items repeated with each additional call to the print screen?

That is happening because the toString() method of the List is putting all the items in the list into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with JComboBox but rather with your expectations. `System.out.println(bIHELessons.toString());` will print out the entire contents of the `bIHELessons` ArrayList. Since you're adding a new String to the ArrayList on each iteration, it's logical that your `System.out.println(bIHELessons.toString());` would show a progressive accumulation of content.

Your question isn't clear but you may consider moving the System.out.println outside of your loop and determining if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the ToString() representation of your entire list.  If you want to print out the object you could just print out the lessons variable instead.